# compatibility of my ubuntu 16.04 with my lenovo pc

Tags: 64-bit

will anybody tell if my pc is compatible with ubuntu 16.04 ,64bit. `lscpu` gives the following output on my pc:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1599.992
CPU max MHz:           3400.0000
CPU min MHz:           1600.0000
BogoMIPS:              6785.10
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx f16c lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
```

Comment: The best way to find out is to boot a Ubuntu Live DVD and select the "Try Ubuntu" mode. Make sure to test your wireless, your video card, and your sound card.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements:

```
Ubuntu Desktop Edition

    700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
    512 MiB RAM (system memory)
    5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
    VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
    Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
    Internet access is helpful
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a  Ubuntu Certified Hardware list where you can check the compatibility - 
https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop&vendors=Lenovo

If your system is not part of the list, then it does not necessarily mean it is not compatible. Nowadays, almost all PC are compatible with Ubuntu. If there is a problem it is mostly related to Wifi or GPU drivers. As per my experience, I have never faced any hardware compatibility issue with Ubuntu except for Nvidia GPU drivers.